# alternative way to set Class in GenericDao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I saw [this](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/08/simplifying-the-data-access-layer-with-spring-and-java-generics/) generic for Hibernate Dao. Heres the content.

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao< T extends Serializable > {

   private Class< T > clazz;

   @Autowired
   SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public final void setClazz( Class< T > clazzToSet ){
      this.clazz = clazzToSet;
   }

   public T findOne( long id ){
      return (T) getCurrentSession().get( clazz, id );
   }
   public List< T > findAll(){
      return getCurrentSession().createQuery( "from " + clazz.getName() ).list();
   }

   public void create( T entity ){
      getCurrentSession().persist( entity );
   }

   public void update( T entity ){
      getCurrentSession().merge( entity );
   }

   public void delete( T entity ){
      getCurrentSession().delete( entity );
   }
   public void deleteById( long entityId ){
      T entity = findOne( entityId );
      delete( entity );
   }

   protected final Session getCurrentSession(){
      return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   }
}
```

then GenericDao

```
@Repository
@Scope( BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE )
public class GenericHibernateDao< T extends Serializable >
  extends AbstractHibernateDao< T > implements IGenericDao< T >{
   //
}
```

then the Service Implementations

```
@Service
class FooService implements IFooService{

   IGenericDao< Foo > dao;

   @Autowired
   public void setDao( IGenericDao< Foo > daoToSet ){
      dao = daoToSet;
      dao.setClazz( Foo.class );
   }

   // ...

}
```

I don't like the way that I need to call setClazz method, just to pass the class. Is there an alternative way? Or is there a way to call the Foo class inside <>.    IGenericDao< Foo > dao;

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, but unfortunately i could not find a clean solution I only added an abstract function inside AbstractHibernateDao which forces the developers to override the function which the class so they dont forget to set the class by mistake.